# Wildcards in Python?

Tags: python, pattern-matching, tuples, wildcard, iterable-unpacking

Over the years I have noticed the 'wildcard' variable in various bits and pieces of Python I've come across. I assumed it worked like Haskell: allowing you to put a variable where one was required in the formal parameters, but not binding it.

I've used this on, for example, the left hand side of an tuple-unpacking assignment when I don't need one of the variables.

For example:

```
_, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
```

So when I wrote something similar to this today:

```
(lambda (x,_,_): x)((1,2,3))
```

I.E. I tried to bind the underscore twice, I received a syntax error. I was surprised to see that _ is indeed a real variable:

```
(lambda (x,_,z): _)((1,2,3))
> 2
```

Looks like `_` is just a variable name like any other.

Is there a bona fide wildcard variable that I can use as I would like (i.e. able to use more than one in a tuple unpacking assignment), as per the first example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no wildcard variable in Python.

I try to dissuade people from using `_` as a variable name for quite some time now.  You are not the first person mistaking `_` as some kind of special syntax, so it's better not to use `_` as a variable name at all to avoid this kind of confusion.  If there ever was a "convention" to use `_` as a throw-away variable name, this convention was misguided.

There are more problems than just the confusion it causes.  For example, `_` clashes with `_` in the interactive interpreter and the common gettext alias.

Regarding the `lambda` expression, I'd just use `lambda x, *args: ...` to ignore all arguments except for the first one.  In other cases, I'd use names explicitly stating I don't want to use them, like `dummy`.  In case of loops of `range()`s, I usually use `for i in range(n)` and simply don't use `i`.

**Edit**: I just noticed (by looking at the other answers) that you use tuple unpacking in the argument list, so `lambda x, *args: ...` doesn't solve your problem.  Tuple unpacking in parameter lists has been removed in Python 3.x because it was considered too obscure a feature.  Better go with [mipadi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969247/wildcards-in-python/7969373#7969373) instead.

Answer (score 3):

No, Python doesn't have any equivalent to Haskell's `_`. The convention in Python is to use `_` for "throwaway" variables, but it's an actual variable name, and as you found, you can't use it twice in the same context (like a lambda parameter list).

In the examples you gave, I'd just use indexing:

```
lambda tup: tup[0]
```

or

```
lambda tup: tup[1]
```

Not as pretty, but one of the better ways to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Not really. Python is not Haskell. Map, apply, reduce, and lambda are kind of second-class citizens, though there is some interesting stuff in itertools.

Unless you have some need to use one-line lambdas, the correct way is this:

```
def f(x, *args, **kwargs):
    return x
```

The `*args` argument lets you use any number of unnamed arguments (which will be available as a tuple called `args`). Extra named arguments will be in a dictionary called `kwargs`.

I don't think there's any way to do this in a lambda, but there's usually no need. A function declaration can go anywhere. Note, you do interesting / evil stuff if you put the function definition inside another function (or loop):

```
def make_func(s):
    def f(*trash, **more_trash):
        print s
    return f

f1 = make_func('hello')
f2 = make_func('world')
f1(1,2,'ham','spam')
f2(1,2,a=1,b=2)
```

will output:

```
>>> hello
>>> world
```

As @rplnt pointed out, this won't be the same for loops:

```
funcs = []
for s in ('hello','world'):
    def f():
        print s
    funcs.append(f)

for f in funcs:
    f()
```

will output:

```
>>> world
>>> world
```

because loops only have one namespace.

Comment: In python 3 this also works on unpacking, e.g.: `(a, *rest, b) = [1,2,3,4]`

Comment: Also, loops shouldn't be a problem as they don't have their own namespace.

Comment: Also, you sure can use `*` and `**` with lambdas.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, with a little trick:

```
class _: 
    def __eq__(x,y): return true
_=_() #always create a new _ instance if used, the class name itself is not needed anymore

[(a,b) for (a,_,_,b) in [(1,2,3,4),(5,6,7,8)]]
```

gives

```
[(1, 4), (5, 8)]
```

I'm using it often, because it makes code more elegant,
a part of Haskells beauty in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no.  Could just follow your existing convention.  That is

```
(lambda (x, _1, _2): x)((1,2,3))
```